# MACRO that converts enum to type in c

Tags: c, types, macros, arm, c-preprocessor

I'm trying this for over a week with no success.

I'm creating a logger interface between two processors and I need help with defining automated MACROS.

What do I mean? 
Let's say I have a logger message defined as `LOGGER_MSG_ID_2` that takes two parameter of uint8 and uint16 types.

I have an enum defined as:

```
typedef enum{
    PARAM_NONE,
    PARAM_SIZE_UINT8,
    PARAM_SIZE_UINT16,
    PARAM_SIZE_UINT32
}paramSize_e;
```

So `LOGGER_MSG_ID_2` will have a bitmap defined as:

```
#define LOGGER_MSG_ID_2_BITMAP   (PARAM_SIZE_UINT16 << 2 | PARAM_SIZE_UINT8)
```

This bitmap is 1 Byte size, so the maximum number of parameters is 4.
Later on I have a list that defines all parameters type according to message ID:

```
#define ID_2_P0_TYPE                                uint8  // first parameter
#define ID_2_P1_TYPE                                uint16 // 2nd parameter
#define ID_2_P2_TYPE                                0      // 3rd parameter
#define ID_2_P3_TYPE                                0      // 4th parameter
```

As I said, I have a limitation of 4 parameters, so I would like to define them and let the MACRO decide weather to use them or not. I defined them as 0 but it can be whatever that works.

I have other MACROS that uses the bitmap to get all kind of attributes, such as number of parameters and message size.

Now it's the tricky part. I want to build a MACRO that creates a bitmap from types. The reason is that I don't want redundancy between the bitmap and parameters definitions.
My problem is that everything I tried failed to compile.

Eventually I would like to have a MACRO such as:

```
#define GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(_type)
```

that gives me PARAM_SIZE_UINT8, PARAM_SIZE_UINT16 or PARAM_SIZE_UINT32 according to type.

Limitations: I'm using arm compiler on windows (armcl.exe) and C99. I can't use C11 `Generic()`.

I tried the following:

```
#define GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(_type)       \
(_type == uint8) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT8 : \
        ((_type == uint16) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT16 : \
                ((_type == uint32) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT32 : PARAM_NONE))
```

Eventually I want to use it like:

```
 #define LOGGER_MSG_ID_2_BITMAP              \
    (GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(ID_2_P3_TYPE) << 6 | \ 
     GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(ID_2_P2_TYPE) << 4 | \ 
     GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(ID_2_P1_TYPE) << 2 | \
     GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(ID_2_P0_TYPE))
```

But when I use it, it doesn't compile.

I have a table of bitmaps:

```
uint8 paramsSizeBitmap [] = {
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_1_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_1   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_2_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_2   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_3_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_3   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_4_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_4   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_5_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_5   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_6_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_6   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_7_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_7   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_8_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_8   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_9_BITMAP,                         /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_9   */
    LOGGER_MSG_ID_10_BITMAP,                        /*  LOGGER_MSG_ID_10  */
};
```

And I get this error:

```
line 39: error #18: expected a ")"
line 39: error #29: expected an expression
```

(line 39 is `LOGGER_MSG_ID_2_BITMAP`)

Where do I go wrong?

----- Edit -----

For now I have a workaround that I don't really like.
I don't use uint64 so I made a use of `sizeof()` MACRO and now my MACRO looks like this:

```
#define GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(_type)       \
(sizeof(_type) == sizeof(uint8)) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT8 : \
        ((sizeof(_type) == sizeof(uint16)) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT16 : \
                ((sizeof(_type) == sizeof(uint32)) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT32 : PARAM_NONE))
```

and my paraemters list is:

```
#define NO_PARAM                                    uint64

#define ID_2_P0_TYPE                                uint8
#define ID_2_P1_TYPE                                uint16
#define ID_2_P2_TYPE                                NO_PARAM
#define ID_2_P3_TYPE                                NO_PARAM
```

It works fine but... you know...

Comment: Have you checked what the table looks like after preprocessing? Most compilers give option to output preprocessed source file.

Comment: Also, non-trivial macros like `GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE` should be wrapped in parenthesis. Operator precedence may bite you here.

Comment: "This bitmap is 1 Byte size" Then why are you using a uint16? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Lundin The ID is 1 Byte and the bitmap is another 1 Byte.

4 parameters, 2bit each. 4 x 2bit = 8bit = 1 Byte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the solution is to use concatenation operator `##`, and helper defines.

```
// These must match your enum
#define HELPER_0      PARAM_NONE
#define HELPER_uint8  PARAM_SIZE_UINT8
#define HELPER_uint16 PARAM_SIZE_UINT16
#define HELPER_uint32 PARAM_SIZE_UINT32

// Secondary macro to avoid expansion to HELPER__type
#define CONCAT(a, b) a ## b

// Outer parenthesis not strictly necessary here
#define GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(_type) (CONCAT(HELPER_, _type))
```

With that `GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(ID_2_P1_TYPE)` will expand to `(PARAM_SIZE_UINT16)` after preprocessing.

Note that suffix in `HELPER_***` defines has to match exactly the content of `ID_*_P*_TYPE` macros. For example `HELPER_UINT8` won't work (invalid case). (Thanks @cxw)

Comment: Very nice!  I would suggest pointing out explicitly in the answer that the `HELPER_` defines are case-sensitive --- `HELPER_UINT8` wouldn't work.  I don't often see mixed-case preprocessor symbols.

Comment: Life saver!
Didn't know the ## operator! I have so many things to use it on!

Comment: @DrorNohi `##` is useful, but use it carefully. It often leads to macro mess which is hard to maintain.

Comment: @user694733 My bad, that seems indeed to be the case. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that `==` is not supported for *types*, only for *values*.  Given

```
uint8 foo;
```

you can say `foo==42` but not `foo == uint8`.  This is because types are not first class in C.

One hack would be to use the C preprocessor stringification operator `#` ([gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/cpp/Stringizing.html)).  However, this moves all your computation to runtime and may not be suitable for an embedded environment.  For example:

```
#define GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(_type)   (    \
(strcmp(#_type, "uint8")==0) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT8 : \
        ((strcmp(#_type, "uint16")==0) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT16 : \
                ((strcmp(#_type, "uint32")==0) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT32 : PARAM_NONE)) \
)
```

With that definition,

```
GET_ENUM_FROM_TYPE(uint8)
```

expands to

```
( (strcmp("uint8", "uint8")==0) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT8 : ((strcmp("uint8", "uint16")==0) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT16 : ((strcmp("uint8", "uint32")==0) ? PARAM_SIZE_UINT32 : PARAM_NONE)) )
```

which should do what you want, although at runtime.

Comment: Wow. Nice hack!
But unfortunately you're right. I must have it preprocessed.

Comment: @DrorNohi Are you open to an extra preprocessing step, or does it have to be just in C?  I maintain a [Perl-based preprocessor](https://github.com/d-ash/perlpp) that might be useful.

Comment: @DrorNohi Actually, I think user694733 has nailed it :) .  Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this doesn't directly answer the question. But you should reconsider this whole code.

First of all, `_Generic` would have solved this elegantly.

The dirty alternative to untangle groups of macros like these, would be to use so-called [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), which are perfect for cases such as "I don't want redundancy between the bitmap and parameters definitions". You can likely rewrite your code with X macros and get rid of a lot of superfluous defines and macros. How readable it will end up is another story.

However, whenever you find yourself this deep inside some macro meta-programming jungle, it is almost always a certain indication of poor program design. All of this smells like an artificial solution to a problem that could have been solved in much better ways - it is a ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (not to be confused with X macros :) ). The best solution most likely involves rewriting this entirely in simpler ways. Your case doesn't sound unique in any way, it seems that you just want to generate a bunch of bit masks.

Good programmers always try to make their code simpler, rather than making it more complex.

---

In addition, you may have more or less severe bugs all over the code, caused by the C language type system. It can be summarized as:

- Bit shifts or other bitwise arithmetic should never be used on signed types. Doing so can lead to all manner of subtle bugs and poorly-defined behavior.
- Enumeration constants are always of type `int` which is signed. You should avoid mixing them with bitwise arithmetic. Avoid enums entirely for programs like this.
- Small integer types such as `uint8_t` or `uint16_t` get implicitly type promoted to `int` when used in an expression. Meaning that the C language will bandwagon most of your attempts to get the correct type and replace everything with `int` anyway.
- The resulting type of your macros will be `int`, which is not what you want.

Comment: _Generic is not supported by my Compiler unfortunately.